# jQuery sortable not working on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Trying to use jQuery's sortable.js on a series of divs coming from a database, but nothing happens when trying to drag-and-drop!

JS code:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
    $( ".menu" ).sortable({
    items:'.menuSort'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Body code:

```
 <div class="menu">
    <?php
    foreach($data as $head){
    ?>
    <div id="header_<?php echo $head->id ?>" class="menuSort">
        <h2 class="menuHeadTitle">
            <?php 
            echo $head->name;
            ?>
        </h2>
        <p class = "menuHeadDescription">
            <?php 
            echo $head->description;
        ?>
        </p>
        <br/>
        <div class="menuHeadItems">
            <?php
            foreach($head->items as $item){
            ?>
                <div class="menuItem";
                    <p class="itemName">
                        <?php 
                        echo $item->name;
                        ?>
                    </p>
                    <p class="itemPrice">
                        <?php 
                        echo $item->price;
                        ?>
                    </p>
                    <p class="itemDescription">
                        <?php 
                        echo $item->description;
                        ?>
                    </p>
                    <br/>
                </div>
            <?php 
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php 
    }
    ?>  
</div>
```

The page is for a restaurant menu: there should be a div for each header (Starter, Main, etc.), with a nested div for each dish under each header. I'm trying (for now) to get the headers sortable, and hope to have the dishes sortable too, but nothing's happening when clicking and dragging on any of the header divs (well, I'm selecting text - but that's not really what I want).

Have tried both jQuery 1.11 and 1.10 to no avail.

EDIT: think it might be something to do with z-axes but I have tried to push the header div to 10000 on the z-xis and still no results.

EDIT 2: Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/SBN84/

Comment: can you create a fiddle with the generated html ?

Comment: I haven't used fiddle - will try set that up now. Will it work with the php or should I provide sample data? 
EDIT: Hang on - just got the bit about "generated" data. D'oh. On that now.

Comment: Just get the generated html from the browsers' developer toolbar/console. That way you have day to play around with. Fiddle is a very simple and useful tool to try out things.

Comment: Haha that's awesome! Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/SBN84/
It's the blue parts that I'd like to be able to rearrange.

Comment: Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/SBN84/5/

Comment: You're amazing! Was it literally just telling it to attach to the > elements?

Comment: Ahh need to use 1.9.x as well. Thank you! Do you wanna add that as an answer and I can mark as answered and give you the rep?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on your fiddle, Here is an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SBN84/5/). You basically needed to select a jquery version, jquery ui. Note that `>` is not mandatory.

```
$(function () {
    $(".menu").sortable({
        items: '> .menuSort'
    });
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Have it working nicely now (also got sub-items sortable and movable between each heading :D ). Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is not working for me.  I believe my problem may be where to place jquery code and which jquery version I use.  Any help?